# In Python, making a list that the user inputs into, and checking if 2 values are present

Tags: python

I've got an assignment that reads like this:
"You've got to have 4 out of 6 hand-ins to pass the subject and need both assignment 4 and 6 to be eligible for the exam. Make a function that returns true if you have enough approved hand-ins. The function should have a list as a parameter where list[0]=1 means the hand-in number 1 is approved, list[1]=0 means that hand-in number 2 is not approved".

I'm really stuck here, and I've spent hours googling and reading forums here at SO, but I can't seem to understand what I have to do.

Can someone please help? 
Thanks - in advance.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a handin factory, you will need to try your self and when you run into an error, you can check if the question has been asked before, if not you can ask it here on SO :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to edit your question summarizing the problem with a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that will make it easier for answerers to help you. You can find more useful tips to improve your question in [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Your questions looks a bit unclear to me. But what I've got would result into the following:

```
def validator(alist):
  return (alist[3] and alist[5] and sum(alist)>=4)
```

The function above will check if 3rd index (4th assignment) is 1 and 5th index(6th assignment) is 1 and the total no. assignments approved is greater than or equal to 4. 
I think this is what you asked.